# Get AppID of all installed applications (Tizen Native app development)

Tags: tizen, tizen-native-app

How can I get the appId of all the applications installed on my tizen device/emulator? I want to get all the appId's and their name and then launch a particular app by comparing that the name of app is the app what I want to launch.

Comment: What research have you done? Have you checked the Tizen native API reference (e.g. the `AppManager` or `PackageManager`) to see if it contains anything you could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Tizen::App::Package::PackageManager::GetPackageInfoListN()](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.2.0/org.tizen.native.apireference/classTizen_1_1App_1_1Package_1_1PackageManager.html#ac3445d2d8170368c53c8695fbbaac118)

Comment: The link is obsolete, Please Update, Thanks.